# What's wrong in using \textbf{} to write \title{}?

Tags: titles, bold

Which would be a better approach to have a bold title?

Comment: The better approach would be to tell your document class to format the title in bold. This will probably be done by changing some internal definitions or (if we're lucky) via a user-facing option/command. How it can be done in your case depends on the document class you use and the way you currently typeset your title. If you want concrete help, we need to see a short example document that reproduces your status quo.

Comment: Please clarify the rationale for your query. It's not clear to me if you're asking (a) it's a bad idea in general to use **bold-facing** for a title (e.g., could it be a bad idea because needless bold-facing can make the title page look vulgar and tacky?) or (b) if there's a more efficient way than `\textbf{...}` (or, equivalently, `{\bfseries ...}`) to generate a bold-faced title string?

Comment: I don't think redefining `\@maketitle` is a *satisfying* “approach to have a bold title” but for the *right* approach more information about the used class and packages are needed. (And sadly, there is not *one* right approach for this.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I think "redefine title layout" is the satisfying approach. Admitedly redefining an `@` command using a pile of tex primitives is less so, but the standard classes are what they are:-) As you say, more modern classes and packages may provide a better interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely against all of the design of LaTeX. You could avoid `\title` at all, and avoid `\section` and just have explicit font changes in the document but the idea is, as far as possible, to just have generic structural markup in the document which may be styled in different ways in different document classes.

If you have `\title{My document}` it might need to be bold in the title page, but perhaps it needs to be in the pdf bookmarks (which have no fonts) or perhaps it needs to be extracted into a collected works table of contents or a citation database and set no-bold. Stripping unwanted style markup without losing semantically required commands is error prone and it's better not to add it.

The font chosen is just part of the overall design of the title layout and any changes should be done in that context not inline.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Some Document}
\author{A. Nother}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% copied from article.cls, then adjusted
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
%    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    {\Large\bfseries \@title \par}%smaller but bolder
%    \vskip 1.5em%
    \vskip 1.1em% smaller
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
%    {\large \@date}%
    {\@date}% smaller
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
\title{Some Document}
\author{A. Nother}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```